# Como alterar a cor do texto dos itens de menu da ActionBar?

Tags: java, android

Além de alterar o texto do item de menu, como faço para alterar o fundo do menu que fica suspenso? No caso, o que só aparece ao clicar nas 3 bolinhas.

Comment: Alterar para uma cor qualquer ou entre *Dark* e *Light* do próprio sistema?

Comment: Cor qualquer, para diferenciar da ActionBar!!

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo você migrar de ActionBar para Toolbar.
No Toolbar, você pode alterar o tema do popup que o item menu abrirá como ação.
Dê uma olhada em: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Mas caso opte por utilizar o ActioBar, você pode fazer o seguinte:
1) Para alterar cor de texto do Item Menu do action:

```
<style>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

E para alterar o popup/dialog que o Item Menu irá abrir, dê uma olhada na seção 'Creating a Popup Menu' deste link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu

Espero ter ajudado.
Boa sorte!